# crossdomain.xml and security issues

Tags: security, crossdomain.xml, session-hijacking

I read a lot about cross-site scripting with Flash, Javascript etc. and also found several lists with websites that have a crossdomain.xml that allows access from any server. For example flickr.com trusts all domains.

Can somebody explain me why this seems to be secure and doesn't lead to attacks like session-hijacking? Is it because those crossdomain.xml is only valid on subdomains, that don't make it possible for an attacker to get the session key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using crossdomain.xml files [can be very dangerous](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/11/08/how-bad-crossdomain-policies-expose-protected-data-to-malicious-applications/) and can open websites up to serious attacks.  There are two rules of thumb to prevent crossdomain policies from opening up security holes:

1. Never put a crossdomain policy file on an intranet site
2. Never put a crossdomain policy file on a site that uses cookies

A valid use of a crossdomain policy file is on a site like api.flickr.com where there are only services which do not use cookies.

Comment: +1 The key point is that api.flickr.com does not use cookies for its services, and so an attacker website cannot misuse the users credentials.